# Where are OAuth 2.0 with Gmail for Server-Side Authorization examples for Java?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I need to implement OAuth2 for a web application written in Java to access Gmail. Unfortunately Google's documentation has only a Python example regarding this topic:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server

I've googled now for hours and could not find a good example which explains the topic - I'm new to OAuth2 and therefore a step-by-step example in Java would be very useful.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

Comment: @VladBochenin thanks for your comment. Yes, I've seen this, but the problem with this example is, that "public static Credential authorize()" prints to the commandline only instead of returning the url to redirect the user. I don't know but as fas as I understand I can't use the code for a web application..

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to make a contribution to the Gmail Quickstart Guides.  I think the path of least resistance would be to just copy what I have here.

Assuming that you have your secrets handy, and you have already obtained a refresh_token in a previous authorization process.  You can try this out.

```java
    /**
     * Assuming the user of this application has already obtained an refresh_token, this will create a Credential object
     * using the provided secrets and the provided refresh_token.
     *
     * @param refreshToken   Refresh Token obtained in previous authorization process
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final String refreshToken, final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = getGoogleClientSecrets();

        return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setClientSecrets(clientSecrets)
                .build().setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
    }
```

Full: GmailQuickstart.java

```java
// Copyright 2018 Google LLC
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

// [START gmail_quickstart]
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Label;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListLabelsResponse;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GmailQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "credentials.json";

    private static GoogleClientSecrets getGoogleClientSecrets() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        File credentialJson = new File(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (!credentialJson.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        return GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(credentialJson)));
    }
    /**
     * Launches a small local server on 8888 which facilitates the authorization process from scratch.  In turn creates
     * an authorized Credential object when the user proceeds with the authorization.
     *
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = getGoogleClientSecrets();

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    /**
     * Assuming the user of this application already has an refresh_token handy, this will create a Credential object
     * using the provided secrets and the provided refresh_token.
     *
     * @param refreshToken   Refresh Token obtained in previous authorization process
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final String refreshToken, final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = getGoogleClientSecrets();

        return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setClientSecrets(clientSecrets)
                .build().setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
    }


    private static Credential getCredential(NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        Credential credentials;
        switch (getAuthPreference()) {
            case FULL_AUTH:
                credentials = getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
                break;
            case REFRESH_AUTH:
                System.out.print("please provide refresh_token:");
                String refreshToken = getUserInput();
                credentials = getCredentials(refreshToken, HTTP_TRANSPORT);
                break;
            default:
                credentials = getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        }
        return credentials;
    }

    private static WhatToDo getAuthPreference() throws IOException {
        // Enter data using BufferReader
        System.out.println("You can choose how to authorize your request.");
        System.out.println("\t1) Need to do full authorization");
        System.out.println("\t2) Already have refresh_token handy.  Can provide this next.");
        String userInput = getUserInput();
        if (userInput.equals("1")) {
            return WhatToDo.FULL_AUTH;
        }
        if (userInput.equals("2")) {
            return WhatToDo.REFRESH_AUTH;
        }
        System.err.println("Your Input was incorrect! ");
        return getAuthPreference();
    }

    private static String getUserInput() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        // Reading data using readLine
        String userInput = reader.readLine();
        return userInput;
    }

    enum WhatToDo {
        FULL_AUTH,
        REFRESH_AUTH
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredential(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Print the labels in the user's account.
        String user = "me";
        ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
        List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
        if (labels.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No labels found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Labels:");
            for (Label label : labels) {
                System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
// [END gmail_quickstart]
```